# DOMDocument element dimensions

Tags: php, html, domdocument

As far as I can tell it is not possible. So hopefully someone has a solution.

basic question:
Is it possible to get the calculated height of an element.

I've used PHP DOMDocument to create a template class. One example is for invoices.
I have it working perfectly for static data (name,address,invoice number).

Now the problem I'm trying to solve is populating the data so the overflow starts a new page.
I can do this by having a fixed number, "This template only supports 20 entries per page", but reduces flexibility.

If I could calculate the height of `<tbody>` and each `<tr>` block I'm appending, I can start a new page. IE `if( SUM(<TR>) > <TBODY> ) start_new_page()`

My current thinking is to put the data into a hidden div, and use javascript to populate the `<tbody>`, but that sounds like a messy hack.

Edit
The pages are rendered with wkhtmltopdf, so the whole page has a fixed height.

Comment: You cant render markup server side. JS with ajax would be what you want

Comment: Yeah I know, It was wishful thinking. I've used a hidden table, and copied the rows into the main table. Using dataContainer.offsetHeight;dataContainer.appendChild(data[0]);